# MAX1771 Circuit not boosting until manually forced

Tags: power-electronics, dc, boost, switching-regulator

I've designed a circuit for boosting a Li-ion battery (3.3 V - 4.2 V) to 12 V. I am using the [MAX1771](https://www.analog.com/en/products/max1771.html) IC and one of the schematics shown in its datasheet. I've designed it to support a maximum current of 2 A.

I have sent the schematic to manufacture it into a board and assemble it. When it was recently assembled all was working good, but some days after the DC-DC Booster is not working unless I "manually force it"**.

This is the schematic:
[image: Circuit sachematic]

**For "manually force it" I'm referring to shorting the +BATT with EXT pin for like half a second, it's just a touch. After that, the IC starts operating normally.

For sure I have something bad in the circuit or there's something I'm not taking into account...

The E_12VDD is directly connected to a pin in an arduino, when I want to turn on the IC, I use `digitalWrite(E_12VDD, LOW)`. Connecting the E_12VDD directly to GND does not change this strange behaviour.

Comment: What is E_12VDD?

Comment: Where's `E_12VDD` connected to?

Comment: It is directly connected to a pin in an arduino, when i want to turn on the IC i use digitalWrite(E_12VDD, LOW)

Comment: It might also help if you could add a photo showing the physical layout of this switcher with E_12VDD highlighted.  A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: And how is the Arduino powered? Datasheet says you shouldn't apply more than V++0.3V to SHDN. So if Arduino is powered by something else, and E_12VDD is high while  V+ is not there, you have a problem.

Comment: @dim Arduino is powered by the battery as well, it is the MKRZERO

Comment: Are you sure the Arduino pulls that pin down to GND?

Comment: @RohatKılıç sure, shorting manually the E_12VDD pin to ground makes the same behaviour

Comment: Are you starting the circuit loaded or unloaded?

Comment: How does the chip get power, is it through the OUT pin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must choose a MOSFET with a lower gate threshold voltage.  From the [SiS438DN data sheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/64826/sis438dn.pdf):

[image]

The gate drive voltage comes from the battery through the coil and diode at start-up and is necessarily less than or equal to the battery voltage minus the diode drop.  You are operating on the knee of the curve, and as your battery voltage drops, you don't switch the MOSFET hard enough.  You must be right on the edge, because when you touch the gate you pick up the diode drop and the gate has enough voltage to switch on.  Once the 12 volt comes up, you have plenty of gate drive.

Good luck!